htaccess reject requests for specific base paths/directories
I have this PHP code included in my wordpress Functions file and it works, but i'd like to move the logic outside of WP and have it rejected before the wordpress is ever even loaded (htaccess)
We are getting an insane number of Bot requests for /rest/api/*******   which are not even legitimate pages for this site. It uses up a lot of resources generating 404's for these requests.
I'd like to figure out how to deny all requests for /rest/*  or /index.php/rest/*  at the htaccess level.
Here is what i have in PHP...
if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,6) == '/rest/' || substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,16) == '/index.php/rest/'){
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST' );
    exit("Invalid Request");
}


PHP/wordpress/regex are unrelated to the question. Check the route for /rest/ and throw a 403 from apache. It is unclear where your issue is currently with that. You also could look at implementing WAF, manually checking user agent on inbound request, or checking IPs of these requests and blacklisting them in firewall.

I'm not familiar with rewrite rules, so just saying "Check the route for /rest/" does not help me... that's what i am asking for help with

I recommend looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/3783243 in that case.

If you are using an apache server as the base for your service (your wording implies that, but you are not specific) you can use the rewriting module for that. Obviously that module has to be loaded.
That might be a first starting point for your implementation:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?rest/ - [F]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/rest/ - [F]

You should implement such rules in the central http server's host configuration. That is much more efficient than using distributed configuration files (typically called ".htaccess"). Only if you do not have access to the central configuration those files might offer a last option.
I suggest you do not simply copy something from the internet into your production system. For obvious reasons ... You need to understand what you are doing, you need to be able to use the tools you use yourself. You simply should not operate such a service yourself otherwise. So go, test the suggestion in your development environment. Read the documentation of the tool you are using (here the apache rewriting module).
Another thing you definitely want to look into is a protection even before your http server. Something like fail2ban might be an idea if those requests come from identifiable addresses ...

This rewrite rule does not work. Wordpress still gets triggered and my php "Invalid Request" shows.

also it's many ip's hitting i can't decipher a specific pattern to firewall, unfortunately

@DavidWilliams Make sure you implement those rules before any of the wordpress rules, so further up in the configuration file. I suggest you add your current file to the question for clarity.
